# Boundedness of a sequence by finding its Limit.

Tags: calculus

We are given a sequence of {$\frac{5^n}{1+5^{3n}}$}, to determine if the sequence is bounded we get $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$,

then we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{5^n}{1+5^{3n}}$

which we know to be equal to $0$.

From this, can I conclude that the sequence is bounded? Even though the sequence approaches $0$
(convergent)

Comment: Every convergent sequence is bounded, so yes.

Comment: @Oria Ok thank you.

Comment: I am just confused with the zero limit

Comment: What are you confused about? A zero limit means that for high $n$, the values are all close to $0$, So, there is some $N$, such for all $n > N$ the sequence elements are $< 1$. So they are bounded above by $1$. There are only finitely many elements for $n \le N$ so you can just pick the largest of them. So those are bounded too.